# thumbs.db the file is open in windows explorer

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, thumbs.db

All the time I have the problem that I cannot delete - move - rename folders in Windows 7 (also applies to windows 10) on network drives because of the thumbs.db file. It complains: "The action can't be completed because the file is open in Windows Explorer."
I found something in a long thread that works for me.

Comment: You may also stop explorer.exe with `taskkill` and delete that folder with `rd /s` commands.

Comment: Same problem on Windows 10, the workaround from lode also works there

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**short answer:**

windows 7: In explorer: Change file display settings from "details" to "Content"

windows 10: In explorer: View->Layout->List

Now the thumbs.db file can be removed.

**Long answer:**

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/ca2cbc1a-362f-4f01-a8f8-6f05112f1915/windows-7-bug-explorer-locks-thumbsdb-in-most-recently-viewed-folder?forum=w7itprogeneral:

> I accidentally came across a slightly easier fix for this bug.  Instead of setting "Turn off the display of thumbnails and only display icons on network folders" to Enable, **I simply changed the Windows Explorer display setting from "Details" to "Content**".  Then I was able to delete my Thumbs.db files without any complaints from Windows 7, even though I have thumbnails enabled.  After deleting the offending file(s), I just restore the display to "Details" again.

thanks my unknown hero robster8192

Comment: Same problem on Windows 10, your workaround also works. The only difference is that there is no 'Content', but I used 'List' with the same result.

Comment: Win10 on network folder: changing view from Details to List worked. However I did have to try twice. It might have been sufficient just to wait another couple seconds before attempting to delete.  I 2nd the Kudos to @robster8192, thank you!

Comment: The only solution that worked for me was in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1743373/117655) by renaming the file first!

Comment: Doesn't work for me on W10 for a folder on a network share. ACK_stoverflow's solution worked (cut-paste the folder onto the desktop, then delete it).

Answer (score 7):

I had this issue in Windows 11 on a network share, and none of the above solutions worked (changed view / layout, cut/paste on local machine).

However I was able to rename it to _.db, and then I was able to delete the file.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me, even on Windows 10.

Comment: Worked for all but one thumbs.db, that's already a progress, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue, but the file was on a Windows network share.  Changing the view didn't allow me to delete the file.  What I was able to do was to cut and paste the folder containing the Thumbs.db file to my local machine.  Once I did that the folder and its Thumbs.db deleted without issue.

Comment: That worked for a network folder reluctant to Damian Vogel's solution (renaming into _.db). Thanks